# Unable to close VS project properties window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

This may sound ridiculous but I can't figure how to close the project properties window in Visual Studio. There's no X or OK button. Help me.

Comment: That's usually a dockable tab, with its own close button, next to the Pin button. If you're referring to `Project->[Project Name] Properties` -- Child Windows can be closed with `CTRL+F4` -- If this is not the window you're referring to, post an image of it

Comment: Try `Shift-Esc`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I found the solution by myself, sorry for the inconveniences!

Comment: @hmmm If you found a solution to your problem, please make sure to post it (as an answer) and accept it, however simple it may seem. Do also consider elaborating your question so the problem is easier for others in a similar situation to relate to. Doing so makes the question useful to others and avoids people unnecessarily opening the question to help find an answer if an answer was already found.

Answer (score 1):

In you're using VS 2022 none of the steps mentioned here worked for me.  The solution that worked was actually pretty simple, although not intuitive.  If you made changes, select ESC to save the changes. If you look at the code tabs a tab bearing the name of your project will have appeared.  That's actually the tab for the project properties window. Close that tab and the properties window will go away.  If you just want to send the properties window to background, just select any other open tab.

Answer (score -1):

**1.Window Shortcuts.**

Every shortcut key hooked to a window must have a W (Windows);
Ctrl+W,W: browser window.

Ctrl+W,S: Solution Manager (Solution).

Ctrl+W,C: Class View (Class).

Ctrl+W,E: Error list (Error).

Ctrl+W,O: Output window (output Output; output the compilation information of the program; you can configure what information you need to view in VS "Tools" - "Options" - "Debug" - "Output Window").

Ctrl+W,P: Properties window (Property).

Ctrl+W,T: Task list (Task).

Ctrl+W,X: Toolbox (In fact, the tool should be Tool but t has been occupied by the task list).

Ctrl+W,B: Bookmark window (Bookmark Bookmark bookmarks are very useful, if there are thousands of lines of code, adding bookmarks when looking for code is much faster to find).

Ctrl+W,U: Document Outline (OutLine; use the second letter U).

Ctrl+D,B: breakpoint window (breakpoint).

Ctrl+D,I: Immediate window (immediately).

**2. Project function shortcut keys.ctrl is the mandatory function key.shift has added functions to the project.**

CTRL + F6 /CTRL + TAB The next document window is the active form switch (alt+tab in the windows operating system means switching between tasks.

CTRL + SHIFT + F6 /CTRL + SHIFT + TAB to the previous document window (in Windows system operation, I believe everyone knows that shift has the opposite function, haha, it is reflected here).

F7: View the code (in WebForm development, it is to view the background code).

Shift+F7: View the form designer (when in the background cs file, this method is very convenient to jump to the foreground .aspx page).

Ctrl+Shift+N: New project (N means New, so if you need to force a new project in the project, it is naturally the key combination Ctrl+Shift+N).

Ctrl+Shift+O: Open the project (Open).

CTRL + SHIFT + C displays the Class View window (C stands for Class).

CTRL+F4 closes the document window.

CTRL + SHIFT + E displays the resource view (E stands for Explorer).

CTRL + SHIFT + B to generate a solution (B stands for Build, which can also be achieved with F6).

Shift+F6 means to generate the current project (it has been said above that the entire solution can be generated by using f6, so if it is the generation of the current project, it is natural to add the function key shift ).

F4 displays the Properties window. SHIFT + F4 to display the project properties window.

Ctrl+Shift+S: Save all.

Ctrl+Shift+A: New item (A means Add).

Shift+Alt+C: New Class .